# How to I add an element style to text in a viewbag in asp.net MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I want to add an `element-style` to the text and value in a `viewbag`. How would I go about this?

This is is the code

```
ViewBag.Title = "Order No:" + " " + Model.OrderID;
```

and what I want to do is make it bold on the view screen. So it should come out like this for example: **Order No: 5**.

I normally add styles to the tags to bold the text, but in this case I'm completely clueless on what to do.

Comment: What technology in particular are you talking about?

Comment: @deceze .Net I think since is using viewBag

Comment: How about add that tag then?

Comment: Yeah, in MVC. I did, but its not working.

Comment: "MVC" is not particular to Microsoft technologies. If you mean .NET, say .NET.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry, I'm new to this development so I'm not familiar with the terminologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put your `ViewBag.Title` in `span` or `label` tag and then apply styles on it.

```
<span style="font-weight:Bold;">ViewBag.Title</span>
```

Or can directly put it in `<b>` tag

```
<b>ViewBag.Title</b>
```

In **c# code**:

```
ViewBag.Error = "Hi, I am <b>bold</b>"
```

Instead of `<b>` you can put **span** or **label** with style you want.
In **view**:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. What if I want to apply it to only that specific text in the viewbag on a specific page? Since this bolds every single viewbag on every page.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me.

```
@Html.LabelFor(ViewBag.Title, new {@style = "font-weight:Bold"})
```

Comment: This wasn't able to answer my specific question but this is useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you display the viewBag title into the page most probably you are using it in a div tag so add a class to it like my boldOrder then in css file you can set the bold property. If  you don't know hot to add a bold to a text just check this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)